# R Script Run Time

Tags: r

I haven't found anything that directly states whether or not R scripts stop when computer locks after idle time. I have a script that takes several house, I'd like to leave running when I'm asleep. Maybe need to find some documentation to read on this.

I was looking at installr os.manage commands, even looking at creating a task on task manager that will keep my computer awake while it runs. Not sure if I'm looking at this right. Do R scripts run when computer locks?

Comment: By "locks" do you mean when you put the computer into sleep mode? If so, there's a pretty simple answer: don't put it to sleep and turn off automatic sleep until you're done with your script

Comment: By lock I mean after idle time the computer locks itself. I can still put an automatic sleep at the end using the installr package though right? @divibisan

Comment: So long as the computer isn't asleep, r scripts can run - locked or not.

Comment: got it @MelissaKey sorry for the noob question, thanks! think i was overcomplicating and getting confused with other posts i've found

Comment: No problem.  I think most of us would be in trouble if this wasn't the case... there's always that one analysis that just takes forever